# Postfix log to MySQL

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I would like to log datetime, sender and recipient to a MySQL table for all mail send through Postfix/Dovecot (virtual users setup).

How can this be done?

Best regards.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Parsing the logfil seems to be the answer. I was first thinking about using some kind of filter, but all i need is in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parsing and centralizing log files, if you need a generic enterprise level tool, you could use [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/).

**Edit:**
If you need just to import the postfix log, you can use something like:

- http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/mysqmail-postfix-logger
- https://github.com/victor3dptz/postfix-log-to-mysql
- https://github.com/rumaxi/postfix2mysql
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35072493/290087

Comment: I dont need this, i need to append 3 items to a table each time Postfix handles a mail....

Comment: Updated my answer. I thought you need big guns. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need realtime processing you can **parse `/var/log/maillog`** (or whatever your Postfix logfile is) and feed it into *MySQL* from there.

You can do this e.g. during daily / hourly `logrotate` run or you can write a simple `cron` job that will check for any new records in the log file and run it every 1 or 5 or so minutes.